# error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Tried few ways but either of them not worked

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to access the JSON array data from an API and I am getting this error. I've tried replacing it with SnapShot.data()[index]['country'] and SnapShot.data.data()[index]['country'] and also with SnapShot[index]['country'] either of them not worked Please help me to figure it out

Error is : error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (undefined_operator at [covid_tracker] lib\CountryWise.dart:66)

and API and JSON data which I am using is https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries

```
// Here is initialization of 'datas' variable
final String url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries";

  late Future <List> datas;

  Future <List> getData() async{

    var response = await Dio().get(url);
    return response.data;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    datas=getData();
  }
```

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: datas,
          builder:( BuildContext context, SnapShot){
            if(SnapShot.hasData){
              return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,

                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){},
                      child: Card(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.amberAccent,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Image(image: AssetImage("images/wdeath.png",),height: 85,width: 85,),

=======================>            Text(SnapShot.data[index]['country'], //Error is here <============

                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              );
            }
            else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          },
        ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBop1.png)

Here is the picture and in line 66 the error is occurred.

Comment: You should add JSON data example and 'datas' named completion/function details. Also, it would be good to add the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this method, I don't know how efficient it is but it worked.

I have created a separate class for the information I needed like this:

```
class CountryData{
  final String country,cases,deaths,recovered,todayCases,todayDeaths,todayRecovered,flag;

  CountryData(this.country, this.cases, this.deaths, this.recovered, this.todayCases, this.todayDeaths, this.todayRecovered, this.flag);

}
```

And I replaced this below code :

```
late Future <List> datas;

  Future <List> getData() async{

    var response = await Dio().get(url);
    return response.data;
  }
```

with this code

```
List<CountryData> countries = [];

  Future getData() async{

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    for( var c in jsonData){
      CountryData country = CountryData( c['country'],c['cases'].toString(),c['deaths'].toString(), c['recovered'].toString(),
          c['todayCases'].toString(), c['todayDeaths'].toString(), c['todayRecovered'].toString(), c['countryInfo']['flag']);
      countries.add(country);
      print(country.country);
      print(country.flag);
    }
    return countries;
  }
```

And at the place where previously I was getting an error (mentioned in question), there I retrieved the data with the List of class which I defined earlier (List countries = [];) like this:

```
   Image(image: NetworkImage(countries[index].flag),height: 85,width: 85,),
                                Text( countries[index].country,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
```

Don't know what is wrong with the method of retrieving the data with the snapshot earlier but this code worked for me.